# How am I suppose to reach the handle?

Tags: mirrors-edge

I am stuck at this part where the big guy in the suit just got killed and you have to escape:

[image]

I have no idea how to get to swinging bar thing.

After you climbed up, you get to a platform(on the right) where you should be able to go the handlebar but it's impossible.

How am I suppose to reach that?

Comment: I can't give you a definitive answer, because I last played this years ago (which is why I'm adding a comment instead), but have you tried wall running off of the platform on right (in screenshot) and jumping off towards the swinging bar?

Comment: @Chippies Yeah I tried it a few times. Not really working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to wallrun up the wall on the left (in screenshot) and jump back to hang on to the pipes.
To understand better watch this video at 5:40

Answer (score 0):

Just climb on the left wall and reach for the pipes behind you (maybe the blue fence if you side jumb). You don't really need that handle after all, do you?

Answer (score 0):

I just passed here ...
Climb from pipes ( in your left) and jump on blue fence then walk on the wall behind yourself ( in picture ) and then jump and grab the handle and go through the door.